# Unable to pass data using Angular9

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-ng-if, angular-bootstrap

I have an array of data fetch from the back-end. The data should be like this

[image]

**UI**
[image]
Bind above data to a table using the following code

**HomeComponent.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover" id =jres>     
          <thead>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
              {{col}}
            </th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let jre of jreArray">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let col of index" >
                    <td *ngIf='col !=="location"'>{{jre[col]}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf='col ==="location"' ><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Download" (click) ="download()"></td>
                </ng-container>             
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

**HomeComponent.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private rs:RestService,private service:JreServiceService) { 
   
  } 
  columns= ["ID","JRE Name","Base Package","Download"];
  index=["id","jrename","basepackage","location"]
  jreArray: Array<IJre> = [];
  searchkey: any;
  path:any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getAllJre().subscribe(data=>{
      this.jreArray =  data;
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
 
  download(){
    alert(this.path)
    this.service.download(this.path).subscribe(data=>{
      this.jreArray = data;
    })
  }
}
```

my requirement to pass the location value to the component.ts  when i click Download button.I have tried below logics

1.ngModel

2.Pass value directly to the method using below code

```
 <td *ngIf='col
    ==="location"' ><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Download" (click) ="download(jre[col])"></td>
```

Is there any simple way to solve this issue.
Please give an advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

i have made below changes.now i can able to pass location.

```
<tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let jre of jreArray">
              <td >{{jre.id}}</td>
              <td >{{jre.jrename}}</td>
              <td >{{jre.basepackage}}</td>
              <td ><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Download" (click) ="download(jre.location)"></td>       
          </tbody>
```